# Concat an array of obects obfuscates the objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to add an object to my array but when I access it it simply shows [object Object]

I have several array of objects which I want to link together into a single array of objects.

I have tried to .concat() and .push with no luck always the same answer.

Important to note `response` is a response from the server so it changes everytime, thus the need to concatenate them in a "final" array

When I call `console.log(response[x])` I get the expected result

```
{
    Name : John,
    surname : doe, 
    Age : 30,
    face : Object {
        eyes : brown, 
        hair : dark
    }
}
```

but when I assign it to res I get `[object Object]`

Here is the code:

```
res = []; 
response = [{Name:John, surname:doe, Age: 30, face: Object{eyes:brown, hair:dark}},{Name:Jane, surname:doe, Age: 35, face: Object{eyes:blue, hair:blond}];

for(var x = 0; x < response.length; x++ ){
//push individual object to the etnire response "res" array
    res[x] = response[x];
    //res.push(response[x])
    //res = res.concat(response) (getting rid of the surrounding array of course)
    console.log("res = " + res[x]);
    //console.log(response[x])
}
```

I am expecting to get something along the lines of a copy of each array into the "final" array so for this example it would be:
`res` would equal  `[{Name:John, surname:doe, Age: 30, face: Object{eyes:brown, hair:dark}},{Name:Jane, surname:doe, Age: 35, face: Object{eyes:blue, hair:blond}]`
and each new object would be added to the existing array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the console log that is used wrongly as you are converting an **object** to a **string**.

Try `console.log("res = ", res[x]);`

Comment: sigh, unbelievable Ive been stuck at this so long.

Comment: holiday time, it will benefit everyone :)